# Point of the `antecedent` argument of the argument of `Task.ContinueWith`?

Tags: c#, closures, task-parallel-library

Given a `Task t`, is there any semantic difference between

```
t.ContinueWith(ante => DoSomethingWith(ante));
```

and

```
t.ContinueWith(ante => DoSomethingWith(t));
```

, assuming that `t` is not mutated later?

Does the `antecedent` argument exist only to avoid the allocation of a closure as in the second variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the antecedent argument exist only to avoid the allocation of a closure as in the second variant?

Effectively, yes.  It also lets you write this more succinctly as:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoSomething())
             .ContinueWith( t => DoSomethingWith(t));
```

It also provides a similar API to using `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll` or `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`.